# I am having issue in replacing \117 in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing an issue with replacing () from a string.
After using the below code snippet.

$str = "UPI\11770918";
echo str_replace('\', '~', $txn_desc);

After execution, I am getting the below response.

```
UPIO70918
```

My desired output was

```
UPI~11770918
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: The part `\117` denotes a octal number. Add another backslash to the first one, this will prevent the escape sequence from being triggered.

Comment: @Lars Stegelitz: If the questions are answered in the comments, they remain in the system as unanswered and can neither be rated nor accepted.

Comment: @umesh, you have to use like below `$str = 'UPI\11770918'; 
 echo str_replace('\\', '~', $str);`  use single quotation

Comment: With single quote it's working but I am getting string in double quotes that why I got stuck

Comment: Reason not to reopen this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php#:~:text=to%20display%20a,another%20backslash

Answer (score 0):

\117 is interpreted as an ASCII character "O" in octal notation. So that the backslash loses its meaning, you have to escape it in the strings.

```
$str = "UPI\\11770918"; 
echo str_replace("\\", '~', $str);
// UPI~11770918
```

Without escaping, the string "UPI\11770918" remains unchanged in your code. This is only output as "UPIO70918" with an echo. The comparison

```
var_dump("UPI\11770918" === "UPIO70918");
//bool(true)
```

shows that both strings are identical.

Comment: I need to extract  "11770918" from "UPI\11770918" can you please help me to get this value

Comment: I think the string contains something else and "UPI\11770918" is the wrong notation for your string.
Please give the string with echo bin2hex($str); and show the result.